# How to write a simple jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I wanted to create simple plugin using jquery.
Also suggest me standard practice while writing jQuery plugin.

Please folks suggest me some better pointers.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) (very short and easy) or [this](http://www.authenticsociety.com/blog/jQueryPluginTutorial_Beginner).

Comment: I wrote a step-by-step guide on how to create a jQuery drop shadow plugin you may want to check out here: - [Creating Drop Shadow jQuery Plugin](http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/creating-drop-shadow-jquery-plugin/) With very simple code, you can create a fully functional jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

a good starting pattern looks like:

```
(function($){
   $.fn.yourplugin = function() {
   };
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 2):

### A simple template I created years ago and still works great:

```
(function($) {
    if (!$.myExample) { // check your plugin namespace does not already exist
        $.extend({  //  this will allow you to add your plugin to the jQuery lib
            myExample: function(elm, command, args) {
                //  keep in mind, right here you might want to do a class or data check to determine which direction this call is going
                //  for example, upon init the plugin on an element you may add the plugin name as a class, 
                //      this way, when it's recalled, you can see it alrady has that class and might be calling a command,
                //          thus make an if statemnt to push the process through
                return elm.each(function(index){
                    // do work to each element as its passed through
                    // be sure to use something like
                    //    return elm.each(function(e) { dor work });
                    // as your final statement in order to maintain "chainability"
                });
            }
        });
        $.fn.extend({   //  this gives the chainability functionality seen with $ funcs like: $("#eleID").css("color", "red") <--returns original element object
            myExample: function(command) {
                return $.myExample($(this), command, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
            }
        });
        $.myExample.props = {   //  Here you can establish specific properties to your plugin, prehaps even make them "Over-writable"
            key1: "value",
            key2: "value"
        };
        $.myExample.methods = { //  Here you can establish specific methods/functions for your plguin to carry out and maintain your namespace as well
            key1: function(param) {
                /*  do work */
            },
            key2: function(param) {
                /*  do work */
            }
        };
        //  This next part is not seen in many plugins but useful depending on what you're creating
        $.myExample.init = function(param) {    //  If you have an initialize method to apply, namespace it in here and calll on initializing your plugin
            var key = "value",
                key2 = {
                    subKey: "value"
                };
                /*
                /  run any number of initializing functions here
                /  I prefer to make my param a value that can be a
                /   string with a possible object
                /   the string for holding a base configuration
                /   the object for any change in properties or base values for that config
                */
        };
        $.myExample.defaults = {    //  establish base properties here that can be over-written via .props, but their values should never truly change
            key1: "value",
            key2: {
                prop1: {
                    subKey1: "value",
                    subKey2: "value"
                },
                prop2: {
                    subKey1: "value"
                }
            },
            key3: function(param) {

            }
        };
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Summary and Best Practices while writing a jQuery Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Summary_and_Best_Practices)

```
(function($){
  // $('p').greenify() turns all text in p elements green.
  $.fn.greenify = function() {
    this.css( "color", "green" ); // set text color
    return this; // for chaining;
  };
})(jQuery);
```